# How to get data result array in php

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have data and stored in database, data return with `result_array()`, when data set to `var_dump()`, result like this:

```
array(6) {
    [0] => array(4) {
        ["id_termmeta"] => string(1)"1" 
        ["id_term"] => string(1)"1" 
        ["meta_key"] => string(9)"telephone" 
        ["meta_value"] => string(17)"(021) 456 789 xxx"
    }
    [1] => array(4) {
        ["id_termmeta"] => string(1)"2" 
        ["id_term"] => string(1)"1" 
        ["meta_key"] => string(11)"handphone_1" 
        ["meta_value"] => string(12)"08567890xxx"
    }
    [2] => array(4) {
        ["id_termmeta"] => string(1)"3" 
        ["id_term"] => string(1)"1" 
        ["meta_key"] => string(11)"handphone_2" 
        ["meta_value"] => string(7)"087654321xxx"
    }
    [3] => array(4) {
        ["id_termmeta"] => string(1)"4" 
        ["id_term"] => string(1)"1" 
        ["meta_key"] => string(11)"handphone_3" 
        ["meta_value"] => string(8)"081234567xxx"
    }
    [4] => array(4) {
        ["id_termmeta"] => string(1)"5" 
        ["id_term"] => string(1)"1" 
        ["meta_key"] => string(6)"alamat" 
        ["meta_value"] => string(16)"Jl. Jalan menuju sorga"
    }
    [5] => array(4) {
        ["id_termmeta"] => string(1)"6" 
        ["id_term"] => string(1)"1" 
        ["meta_key"] => string(5)"email" 
        ["meta_value"] => string(20)"blabla@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

I want to get data `meta_value` in `array[0]`, `meta_value` in `array[1]`, `meta_value` in `array[2]`, etc..

How to make like this:

```
<ul class="list-contact">
   <li><a href=""><div class="list-style"><img src="tlpn.png"></div>(021) 456 789 xxx</a></li>
   <li><a href=""><div class="list-style"><img src="phone.png"></div> <p>08567890xxx<br>087654321xxx<br>081234567xxx</p></a><a href=""></a></li>
   <li><a href=""></a><a href=""><div class="list-style"><img src="marking.png"></div>
                            <p>Jl. Jalan menuju sorga</p>
                            </a></li>
   <li><a href=""><div class="list-style"><img src="msg.png"></div>blabla@gmail.com                             </a></li>
</ul>
```

and the result like this:

[image: Sample output]

Comment: where your php code ??, on the other hand you can get data like this $a[0][3] $a[1][3] $a[2][3]

Comment: here my code:  public function get_termmeta_by_id($id)
 {
  $this->db->where('id_term', $id);
  $query  = $this->db->get('db_termmeta');
  return $query->result_array();
 }

Comment: @mohade: thanks bro.. its work..

here the code: <?php echo $contact[0]['meta_value']; ?>

Comment: You are very welcome bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, its worked, thanks @mohade

```
<ul class="list-contact">
   <li><a href=""><div class="list-style"><img src="tlpn.png"></div><?php echo $contact[0]['meta_value']; ?></a></li>
   <li><a href=""><div class="list-style"><img src="phone.png"></div> <p><?php echo $contact[1]['meta_value']; ?><br><?php echo $contact[2]['meta_value']; ?><br><?php echo $contact[3]['meta_value']; ?></p></a><a href=""></a></li>
   <li><a href=""></a><a href=""><div class="list-style"><img src="marking.png"></div><p><?php echo $contact[4]['meta_value']; ?></p>
                            </a></li>
   <li><a href=""><div class="list-style"><img src="msg.png"></div><?php echo $contact[5]['meta_value']; ?></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the foreach

```
// example like this
foreach(data <- datalist){
  echo data.telephone["meta_value"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have the given array of data available in your controller. Let's assume the name this array is`$results`.

**First**

Pass `$results` array to the view which you need to display this results.If your view is `results.php` then your code would be like

```
public function viewResults(){
//Your controller logic
$data = array('results' => $results);
$this->load->view('results',$data);
}
```

**Second**

Now your results array is available in your view and you can use it to get the needed result

The code below is the easiest you can do, but if it is to work properly you should only use `$result` with given format, for example if your array lacks 
`"handphone_1"` all the following values will be shown in wrong places.

```
    <ul class="list-contact">
      <li>
        <a href=""><div class="list-style"><img src="tlpn.png"></div><?php echo $results['0']['meta_value'] ?></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href=""><div class="list-style"><img src="phone.png"></div> <p><?php echo $results['1']['meta_value'] ?><br><?php echo $results['2']['meta_value'] ?><br><?php echo $results['3']['meta_value'] ?></p></a><a href=""></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=""></a><a href=""><div class="list-style"><img src="marking.png"></div><p><?php echo $results['4']['meta_value'] ?></p></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href=""><div class="list-style"><img src="msg.png"></div><?php echo $results['5']['meta_value'] ?></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

To eliminate the problem discussed you can use loop with conditional statements

```
<?php
$count=0; 
foreach($results as $result){ ?>
  <ul class="list-contact">
      <?php if($result['meta_key']=='telephone'){ ?>
          <li>
            <a href=""><div class="list-style"><img src="tlpn.png"></div><?php echo $result['meta_value'] ?></a>
          </li>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php if( strpos($result['meta_key'], 'handphone') !== false ){ 
          if($count==0 ) { ?>

          <li>
            <a href="">
              <div class="list-style"><img src="phone.png"></div>
          <?php $count++; } ?>
              <?php if($result['meta_key']=='handphone_1'){
                  echo $result['meta_value'].'</br>';}
              ?> 
              <?php if($result['meta_key']=='handphone_2'){
                  echo $result['meta_value'].'</br>';}
              ?>
              <?php if($result['meta_key']=='handphone_3'){
                  echo $result['meta_value'];}
              ?> 
            </a>
          </li>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php if($result['meta_key']=='alamat'){ ?>
          <li>
            <a href=""><div class="list-style"><img src="marking.png"></div><?php echo $result['meta_value'] ?></a>
          </li>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php if($result['meta_key']=='email'){ ?>
          <li>
            <a href=""><div class="list-style"><img src="msg.png"></div><?php echo $result['meta_value'] ?></a>
          </li>
      <?php } ?>
  </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hai RanjanaLK: Thanks for your time, I follow your suggestion, but it not work, data show correctly. here my code: http://pastebin.com/Bfz4QtTf   and the result like this: https://postimg.org/image/6x6o0u6f1/

Comment: @ariefbruce I've made a small mistake in my code and that's why you got your results like this https://postimg.cc/image/6x6o0u6f1/ . I've made an edit to the `foreach` it should be all good now.

Comment: RanjanaLK: is it possible to show data like this: https://postimg.cc/image/iy88poly9/ how to make it?

Comment: don't use `<img src="phone.png">` on`handphone_2` or `handphone_3` and you won't be showing the mobile phone icon repeatedly.

Comment: @ariefbruce This seems to be a contacts list for an entity. Is this the only list you have to display or do you have many entities with a contact list like this?. If you have many lists, do all lists have exact format(1 landline,3 mobiles,email,etc)?. What is the final result you got with all above suggestions?

Comment: RanjanaLK: I just want to display data contact from database, here my database https://postimg.org/image/5v4w024df/ , just data contact with id_term=1. data contact can update and display like https://postimg.cc/image/iy88poly9/ but I dont know how to display like that.

Comment: @ariefbruce I've made necessary changes to the code after seeing your DB table. I've tested the code and it's working. This code does not look pretty because of structure of the data array it has to handle.

Comment: RanjanaLK: can you share to me the code that you created. I thank you for your time. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125966/discussion-between-ranjanalk-and-ariefbruce).